# "An unidentified program wants to access your computer" in vista

Tags: uac

How to show the publisher's name instead of "An unidentified program wants to access your computer" in vista?

Comment: It would probably be better to ask your question at http://superuser.com/, as that site is more geared for issues like yours, since this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: @jlech: It is a programming question, in that the OP wants their program to show their company's name instead of "unidentified".

Comment: I voted this down because the same user asked the same question, at time of me writing this, 2 hours ago and 33 minutes ago, with this question being 22 hours ago. Whilst I think it is programming related, the user doesn't think to edit or revisit his existing question before creating a new one, and hasn't read the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

You need to obtain a code-signing certificate (which is different from an SSL server certificate) from a certificate authority, and sign your programs with it. There are certain requirements for obtaining such a certificate; for example, some certificate authorities will require your company documentation, etc.

Comment: It works (your publisher name will appear) with a certificate that is obtained from your own CA. You don't need a commercial one - you'll just get a warning that the certificate is untrusted.

Comment: @sylvanaar: And why would users run a program with an untrusted certificate? We train users not to put in their sensitive information into websites with untrusted certificates, etc.

Comment: @sylvanaar: If you want your program to "look and smell" like the ones that come with Vista, it's gotta be signed by a reputable CA. If you're deploying apps internally only, just add your own corporate CA to the list of trusted CAs for your domain. If you're delivering the app to the general public, a well-known CA is the only way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You need to sign your program with a digital signature.